# Trying to loop through id's with php and on click to get a modal popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops

I have multiple product cards that are being looped by php. I want to add an onclick to the card where a modal pops up. I tried

HTML

```
            <div id="sbf-user-image" class="open-lightbox">



               <img id="user-image<?php echo $count ?>" src="DEMO"

               onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='DEMO';" alt="test" />



            </div>





            <!-- The Modal -->

           <div id="myModal" class="modal">

              <span class="close">CLOSE</span>

             <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="DEMO"

             onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='DEMO';" alt="test" />



              <div id="caption"></div>

           </div>
```

Script

```
var img = document.getElementById("user-image<?php echo $count ?>");

var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");

img.onclick = function(){

    console.log("testing image loop")

modal.style.display = "block";

modalImg.src = this.src;

captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;

}
```

This script above isn't working so I tried just to see if it would hide or do anything at all with the following code and it did. Any idea how i can implement the img.onlick above into this click below?

```
$('.open-lightbox').on('click', function test(){

    $(this).find('img').hide();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is something wrong with your $count, cause I tested this code and while I define $count at the top of code , img.onclick works properly and console logs : "testing image loop".
Anyway if you want to do it in the other way,you may do it like this :

```
var imageElem = $('.open-lightbox').find('img');

$(imageElem).on('click', function test(){
        console.log("testing image loop");
        //and the rest of your code
});
```